# List select range of objects based on property value

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have following list:

```
List<MyType> myList = new List<MyType>
{
    new MyType {Key = "aa", Value = "test1"},
    new MyType {Key = "bb", Value = "test2"},
    new MyType {Key = "zz", Value = "testzz"},
    new MyType {Key = "cc", Value = "test3"},
    new MyType {Key = "yy", Value = "testyy"},
    new MyType {Key = "dd", Value = "test4"},
    new MyType {Key = "ee", Value = "test5"}
};
```

where,

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I would like to retrieve all the objects within the range based on the value of Key. That is, I would like to select all the objects from the list starting from the Key="bb" to Key="dd" (no alphabetic ordering) so that I would have the following result:

```
new MyType {Key = "bb", Value = "test2"},
new MyType {Key = "zz", Value = "testzz"},
new MyType {Key = "cc", Value = "test3"},
new MyType {Key = "yy", Value = "testyy"},
new MyType {Key = "dd", Value = "test4"}
```

How can I achieve this using linq/lambda expression?

**[Update: 12/30/2015]**: The key are NOT ordered alphabetically and there might be hundreds of keys. So, solutions involving list.Contains(..) and assuming alphabetic ordering will not work. I have also updated the example to include objects with keys 'yy' and 'zz' to reflect the same.

Comment: How varied can your criteria actually be? Are they always in a range or can they be completely disjoint? There could be widely different answers depending on this.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a disjoint set of keys then you can use the `Contains` operator:

```
var keys = new [] { "bb", "cc", "dd" };

var result = myList.Where(x => keys.Contains(x.Key));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are talking about the items that are between two specific items (in location, not based on alphabetic order).

Here is how you can do it:

```
bool found_last = false;

var first = "bb";
var last = "dd";

var result = myList.SkipWhile(x => x.Key != first).TakeWhile(x =>
{
    if (x.Key == last)
    {
        found_last = true;
        return true;
    }

    return !found_last;

}).ToList();
```

Comment: Every other answer tries to find entries from the `List<>`, no matter where in the list they are, such that the key of each entry is in between two "extreme" values (`"bb"` and `"dd"`) in some alphabetical way. Your answer interprets the problem differently. You use `"bb"` and `"dd"` to identify the start and end position in the `List<>`, then include every entry in the list positioned in between the start and the end point (both inclusive). Your interpretation is not equivalent to the interpretation of the others. It would be nice if the asker would verify what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `Where`:

```
string start = "bb";
string end   = "dd";

var rows = myList.Where(x => x.CompareTo(start) >= 0 && x.CompareTo(end) <= 0);
```

Comment: Only if the keys are contiguous and have a sort order.

Comment: Indeed. For complex scenarios you have to make an own comparison method.

Comment: _Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'_ you know.

Comment: Yes, ahum. `CompareTo` is better here.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
var kys = new[] { "bb", "cc", "dd" };
var Result = myList.Where(x => kys.Contains(x.Key));
```